# Piano notes with AKKeyboardView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audiokit

I am new to AudioKit - I am able to use the AKKeyboardView to play notes using AKOscillatorBank, but I want the audio to sound more like a grand piano. Loading .wav files seems to make the notes choppy. I have also changed the note envelope. How can I map grand piano notes onto the AKKeyboardView keys?

Comment: Please note you haven’t asked an actual question here. Do edit the question and add a specific question. But if the question is “how do I make it sound like an actual piano?” it is a way too broad question with a lot of different possible answers. The [help] will explain what kind of questions are suitable on this site.

Comment: Thanks, edited with specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not easily going to get a piano sound out of an oscillator.  You might want to use a soundfont instead. You can load an sf2 (but not sf3, I believe) into an AKAppleSampler and trigger it using AKKeyboardDelegate as you are doing with the AKOscillatorBank. [MuseScore has list of soundfont file links](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/soundfonts-and-sfz-files#gm_soundfonts), many of which use open source licenses.

First add the sf2 file to your project, then set up the AKAppleSampler:

```
let sampler = AKAppleSampler()
// note that if you're using a GM soundfont, 'Grand Piano' will be preset 0
sampler.loadMelodicSoundFont("NameOfSoundFontWithoutExtension", preset: 0)
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, if it answers your question.